# Ideas on how to implement bulk edit with the Wpf DataGrid?

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid

(Major question update)

Goal: the ability to select a range of cells (or rows). Update one cell and have that update cascade to all applicable cells (e.g. cells in the same column )

Would also like the Excel behavior of using Enter to commit and move to next cell without losing the selected range.

Tried doing this with the Wpf Datagrid control.. and the result is a kludge..

- The datagrid supports multi-selection using Ctrl / Shift.
- However on entering edit mode (irrespective of SelectionMode and Unit), all other rows are deselected leaving the one being edited as the sole selection. Worked around this by hooking into Mouse-Preview events and caching multiselection if any. Added an IsSelected property to my row ViewModels and used them to modify selected rows at will.
- Edits are committed only after the user tabs out. Used binding with UpdateSourceTrigger set to PropertyChanged. Applied current edit to cached multiselection using a ContainerVm which listened to PropertyChangeNotifications from the RowViewModels.
- DataGrid events were not helpful - by the time BeginningEdit is called, the selection was already modified by the MouseDown handler in DataGridCell.

So Grid events and styling haven't helped. Nor has the ViewModel approach. Another option to try out is to write a derivation of DataGridCell and plug it in somehow.

Ideas ?

Comment: so if you changed a value from 28 to 45 using the keyboard, would you want to see one event (28 -> 45), or two? (28 -> 4, 4 -> 45)?

Comment: @Paul. Now that I think about it, it seems unnecessary for all datatypes (esp text or numbers.. since you're not sure if the user has completed editing). I started with a checkbox column which is what was first on my list and in the case of a checkbox, it is more immediate (true or false). It is not intuitive to see all multiselected checkboxes not update till you tab out. For text and numbers and everything else, I agree the default (LostFocus or EnterKeyPress) should work. I'm going to see if I can get this done using the ViewModel instead of doing Grid-event-y code.